# Splitting a drive which has layout as mirrored and type as dynamic

Tags: hard-drive, raid, windows-server-2012

I have a C drive/volume in my server with layout = mirror and type =dynamic and status as healthy(boot,pagefile,crashdump).

I have some questions regarding this configuration:

1. I think it is a raid configuration.Please correct me if I am wrong. I read that, mirroring is nothing but raid-1 configuration.
2. All my software and OS is in this drive. I want my software to be in a separate drive, but I am not sure if I can create a separate drive from the above mentioned c drive. I want to know:
   a. If I can do it and how ?(using disk management)
   b. If this is a right approach ?

Comment: see this is a genuine question. could you atleast point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes RAID-1 uses two drives and exactly copies the data (mirroring).

If you're talking about partitioning, this is not easily done with vanilla windows tools. (In your case there is already data on the drive.)  Even with other programs it gets messy moving data as the location each program is going to look for it's data will now have changed. It may be as simple as just pointing it in the right direction, however installed programs don't like to be moved.  It is best while installing to select the proper installation location and leave it there; windows is very picky that way.

It is possible but I recommend using third party tools such as Acronis disk director and true imaging home; you'll have to be logical in your thought process to work out the steps of moving information around and backing information up so you don't lose anything; an extra drive to aid in this process would be recommended.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answers. I wanted to partition just because i wanted to keep my software in a different drive. I understand that this decision should have been taken while installing OS but it was decided to yesterday to move the software to a diff drive and hence this question. So if i use a third party tool to split my existing c drive what would happen to the mirrored copy. it would have to be changed as well right? Also i got this server only after the os  was installed so i didnot have a say in the partition.

Comment: If i use a third party tool to split my existing c drive what would happen to the mirrored copy?

Comment: The Raid controller will take care of that, if left mirrored then the second drive will also re-partition just as the first.